# Using ajax posting not getting any responce

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script>
function login() {

    var postData = {
        "UserName": "user@gmail.com",
        "Password": "123",
        "RememberMe": true
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (Data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failure");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

here i am not getting any responce either success message r failure message. please help me

Comment: Maybe because you are posting data to "url" and not a valid http url?

Comment: check if any error in console ???????

Comment: I tried your code with my url working fine. give your **URL**. It's same Domain or Cross Domain.

Comment: Post your server side code..and what is url???

Comment: You have to post that how you are firing this function?

Comment: btw, you should escape the mail

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating these attributes more:

```
data: JSON.stringify(postData),
dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using by the following its works fine.if it not works let me know.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login() {

    var postData = {
        "UserName": "user@gmail.com",
        "Password": "123",
        "RememberMe": true
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "ChangePasswordSuccess.aspx",
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (Data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failure");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This, you might get benefit from xhr.status

```
$.ajax({
    cache: !1,
    type: "POST",
    data: $.toJSON(c),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: e,
    success: function (a) {
        doStuff(a)
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(ajaxOptions);
        alert(thrownError);
        alert(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Note **a** is json response of request made to url **e** While **c** is data to be posted to the url.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not valid ! 
compelete url property of ajax request and test again.